# how to use custom widget as another file in several files in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I made floatinActionButton.dart that is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../components/common/bottom_bar.dart';

class FirstArea extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstArea({Key? key, required Null Function() onPressed, required Icon child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstArea> createState() => _FirstAreaState();
}

class _FirstAreaState extends State<FirstArea> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFB1C5FF),
    );
  }
}
```

and I want to use that widget 'FirstArea' in other files. how can I use that? I don't understand the one thing that is the other files had have already Scaffold, but my widget above has Scaffold too. I mean that Is it possible put the scaffold in the scaffold? how can I work arrange for using that widget above in the other files? please give me any advices. thanks a lot.

Comment: You have to use `FloatingActionButton` as common widget?

Comment: yes, I want to define that only once, so I made it as another file and I imported that in other files and try to use.. @Sugan Pandurengan

Answer (score 0):

Then use this `FirstArea` widget with all parameters for `Scaffold`.

Don't use scaffold in other files. Just call this widget It places scaffold by default.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../components/common/bottom_bar.dart';

class FirstArea extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstArea({Key? key, 
    required Null Function() onPressed, 
    required Icon child,
    required Widget body,
    }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstArea> createState() => _FirstAreaState();
}

class _FirstAreaState extends State<FirstArea> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:widget.body,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt_outlined),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFB1C5FF),
    );
  }
}
```

I have illustrated body parameter here. Use any paramter of scaffold you need.